# not-null property references error when Adding @Column(nullable = false)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a springboot project with two tables/entities having one-to-many relationship below

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"invoiceItemId"}))
public class InvoiceItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long invoiceItemId;
    @Column(nullable =  false)
    private int sn;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoiceId", insertable = false, updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="FK_invoice_item"))
    private Invoice invoice;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="FK_product"))
    private Product product;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double quantity;
//  @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double price;
//  @Column(nullable =  false)
    private Double totalAmount; //add validation later

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"invoiceId"}))
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long invoiceId; //set format
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String invoiceNo;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String customerName;
    private String customerAddress;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String contactNo; //set format
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "userId", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_invoice_sales"))
    private User salesPerson;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String poNumber;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date purchaseDate;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String paymentType;
    private String paymentTerm;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String tinNumber;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date dueDate;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name= "invoiceId", nullable = false)
    private List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems;
    private Double totalAmount;
    
    
}
```

I am using `spring-data-jpa` for this project to handle the database transaction. Initially, I marked the fields in `InvoiceItem` like `quantity` as non-nullable. When running my Unit Test, I don't face any issues at all. I have tested my unit test using H2 and MySQL and test passed on both. However, when I am doing integration testing, I always get below error:

```
not-null property references a null or transient value : com.edar.sales.be.entity.InvoiceItem.quantity
```

This error is thrown for all the fields in the `InvoiceItem` with `@Column(nullable = false)` annotation. What weirded me out is that I only encounter this issue when calling the API endpoint. Also, when I removed the `@Column(nullable = false)` I don't face this error

Comment: Are you sure that the values are set correctly? Because maybe they are actually `null`.

Comment: I am sure they are set correctly. I run the service in debug mode to see that there are actual values. I even set the `Invoice` object in each `InvoiceItem` but still got the the error